# wp-login.php not returning error messages / or gives 404

Tags: wp-login-form

I have several WP sites that were logging in fine last week. Now today thay are all failing to login using the native wp-login.php.

The strange thing is some of the sites have the "Woocommerce" plugin installed, using the plugin login form I can access the dashboard. But not using wp-login.php

I have already tried:

- adding this to wp-config.php

  ```
  /** wp-admin login fix */
  define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
  ```
- re-uploading all wp files apart from wp-content
- Changing file permissions of wp-login.php
- permalinks on and off
- removed .htaccess
- Disabled Plugins
- 100% fresh install of WP 3.6.1 on a new DB

The thing that is confusing me is that I can still login using woocommerce on sites that have it. And the native login was working last week.

Could this be a hosting issue?

Any help / suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Joe

Comment: Have you checked your error logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem has gone. As strangely as it appeared it vanished. I got a call form a client later that day I asked them if they could login, yes they could.

I then tried logging in through my phone this was also successful.

So the problem seemed to be localised to my computer.

I logged in the next day and all was fine. I still don't know what caused the error but its gone now.

Cheers for the comment anyway @birgire